# whats the difference - docker images vs openshift imagestreams?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, imagestream

Could someone explain what is openshift **imagestream** and how it differs from the regular docker image.

I have gone through this ([Understanding containers, images, and imagestreams](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/openshift_images/images-understand.html)) document but it does not explain much about imagestreams.

I understand that docker images are a blueprint to create containers. Just wondering that a imagesteam is??

Answer (score 5):

Like a lot of (all?) kinds in Kubernetes, an `ImageStream` is an abstraction. If you can imagine a `Pod` being an abstraction of the idea of a running container(s), you could imagine an `ImageStream` being an abstraction of the idea of a repository in an image registry (such as quay.io, or the internal container registry in an OpenShift cluster).

Here's an example of [an actual repository in an image registry](https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak?tab=tags), where you can see that it contains a list of tags corresponding to different versions of the image.
[image]

Here's an example of an `ImageStream`, as represented in the OpenShift web console. You can see that it contains a list of tags, just like the previous example of a repository in an external registry.
[image]

Here you can see that the `ImageStreamTags` actually point to different repositories, such as `rhscl/python-27-rhel7`, and `ubi8/python-38`, in the registry. There's even an example of an `ImageStreamTag` pointing  to another `ImageStreamTag` at the bottom of the list. So it's not exactly a 1:1 mapping to an image registry, it's kind of a higher level abstraction.

As an example of when you might choose to use one, imagine you want to run your Python app in your OpenShift cluster. You could have a `BuildConfig` that knows how to build your image, by taking your source code from your Git repository, building it and layering it on top of a Python 3.8 base image. Then when it's built, you want this new version to replace the running version in the cluster.

There are a couple of places that you could benefit from `ImageStreams` here:

1. If the base Python 3.8 image referenced in your `BuildConfig` is an `ImageStreamTag` (such as `python:3.8` in the above example picture) rather than an image tag directly in a repo in a registry; then you could have periodic updates to the `ImageStreamTag`, and if the base image in the repo has been updated, it can trigger a new build of your app image.
2. If your build outputs to an `ImageStreamTag` that's referenced in your `Deployment`, then your `Deployment` can be automatically (or not) updated to roll out the new version of your app.
3. If you wanted to change the base Python 3.8 image to point to a different image (such as from a different vendor in a different registry, or your own custom one) then you just need to update the `ImageStreamTag` in the `ImageStream` which can lead to a rebuild of your app image (and any other builds that you have for other images that reference the `ImageStreamTag`), and again, a new roll out of your app (and any other apps from other such builds).

^This is just one example of how you might make use of an `ImageStream`, and is not meant to be exhaustive.

Comment: almost gave up on this Q. Thx. `to change the base Python 3.8 image to point to a different image,  then you just need to update the ImageStreamTag in the ImageStream`, can this be done using oc cli. If yes what will be the command.

Comment: I believe so, see `oc tag -h` along with https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html#images-imagestreams-update-tag_image-streams-managing